# Match anything when finding a special character in python regex

Tags: python, regex, pywikibot

I want to use a regex that matches anything but when it finds a special character stop from matching.] I want to use this pattern `\*\s*\[\[.*` and when become this : `]]` it stops matching.

For example it should match `* [[anything here]]` or `* [[]]` and it should not match the `* [[anythng here]] anything ]]` or should not match the `* [[]]]]`

I want to use this regex in Python for a Wikipedia bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\*\s*\[\[.*?\]\]
```

The `?` after `.*` above makes the match reluctant/ungreedy.  It will only match up until the *first* instance of `]]` rather than the last.

Comment: Would that only take the first [[*]] pair
ex.) [[[[xxxxxx]]xxxxx]]
the first match would be [[[[xxxxxx]]?

Comment: @eliteslayer it would match `[[[[`, but as far as I can tell that is desirable; to get around that you could do `\*\s*\[\[[^[\]]+?\]\]`, which also requires at least one non-`[`/`]` character

Comment: Thanks dears.This regex is better for my job.